# Media file is played and overlay when i selected item

Tags: android

I have a application in which when i select any item then it will play that media file but when i select other item then the old media is playing continue and the current media file is overlay(current file is also playing) so i am listen both media files.

I have written below code:

```
ImageView songView;
Gallery songGallery;
MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_test);
    songView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.songView);
    songGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.songGallery);


    songGallery.setAdapter(new MyGalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext()));


    songGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int arg2, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            songView.setImageResource(symbolIds[arg2]);

            String imageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                    symbolIds[arg2]);

            Uri audio = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/raw/" + imageName + "");

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), audio);


            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                    mp.reset();
                }

                mp.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        ....
        ....
     }
   }
```

So my question is - When i select the item the song is playing very well but when i select other item then the old song is also playing with the current.

so i want to stop the old song...

I want to play only current selected item song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that MediaPlayer is being recreated instead of being reset. Rather than using the #create() factory call, you can use the constructor instead. In the following code, if the mp is already created it is reset and then a datasource is prepared and started.

```
if (mp != null) {
  mp.reset();
} else {
  mp = new MediaPlayer();
} 

// Now set the datasource 
mp.setDataSource(context, audio);
mp...
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Ideally though you should call prepareAsync and have a callback onPrepare() call the actual mediaPlayer.start so that prepare does not block the main thread.

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mp.setDataSource(..)
mp.prepareAsync();


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `MediaPlayer mp` global variable `private static.` Better yet use Singleton instead of global

Answer (score 0):

You could review the [state diagram here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

then review an implementation of that logic for recycle media player in the 
media sample you can find in your SDK installation:

$SDK/.../src/com/android/sample/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java

and follow how the sample resets the player state before using it again

Comment: Thanks for answer but still i didnt get any solution from this diagram.